# How to fix the forms making the buttons overlap

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I currently have this code :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table align-items-center table-flush">
                    <thead class="thead-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>@lang('strings.id')</th>
                            <th>@lang('strings.name')</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Created at</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($backups as $backup)
                        <tr>
                            <td><code>{{ $backup->uuidShort }}</code></td>
                            <td>{{ $backup->name }}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $backup->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.download', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">@lang('strings.download')</button>
                                </form>
                                <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.deploy', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">@lang('strings.deploy')</button>
                                </form>
                                <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.delete', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">@lang('strings.delete')</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

and it's working perfectly except that the buttons are overlaping :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP6eu.png)
Is there a way to fix it? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can u plz add this in snippet? i cant able to see the output

Comment: The code? If so, here it is : [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3a1m5y5i)

Comment: what output you get?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP6eu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your forms with `<div class="d-flex">[forms here]</div>` or `d-inline-flex` class

```
<div class="d-inline-flex">
  <form class="mr-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Button</button>
  </form>
  <form class="mr-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Button</button>
  </form>
  <form>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Button</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better but not totally like I want : https://i.imgur.com/4P67UWU.png I want that it's on the right and that the buttons are spaced

Comment: Just saw the `d-inline-flex`, now it's on the right like I want but the buttons aren't spaced

Comment: add a class button `mr-2`

Comment: Thanks! With d-inline-flex on the forms and mr-2 on the buttons, it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
      <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.download', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">@lang('strings.download')</button>
                                </form>
</div>
<div>
   <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.deploy', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">@lang('strings.deploy')</button>
                                </form>
</div>

<div>
   <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.delete', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">@lang('strings.delete')</button>
                                </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<td class="text-right">
      <table>
        <tr>
           <td>
              <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.download', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                  {!! csrf_field() !!}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">@lang('strings.download')</button>
               </form>
           </td>
           <td>
              <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.deploy', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                  {!! csrf_field() !!}
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">@lang('strings.deploy')</button>
              </form>
          </td>
          <td>
             <form action="{{ route('server.backupmanager.delete', ['server' => $server->uuidShort, 'backup' => $backup->uuid]) }}" method="POST">
                 {!! csrf_field() !!}
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">@lang('strings.delete')</button>
             </form>
         </td>
     </tr>
```